# Javac splatting operator '@' cannot be used in Powershell and cmd

Tags: java, powershell, cmd, javac

I try to compile a java project with multiple .java files that are in multiple directories. The only flag that I think will help me is the @filename where filename stands for a file with all .java paths.

The PowerShell command that I run is:

```
javac @sources.txt
```

And this is the error:

> The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an
> expression. '@sources' can be used only as an argument to a command.
> To reference variables in an expression use '$sources'.

I mention that I tested this command with cmd and the result is the same.

It is important to compile the java project using powershell, not ant. I am also pleased with a solution that would compile all my .java files without using this option from javac.

What I want to do further is to create a jar file. In order to do this I have to compile the java files.

```
cd $basedir

cmd /r dir "*.java" /s /B  > sources.txt

javac "@sources.txt"
```

That is what I do and the sources.txt file is fine.

Comment: If I execute `cmd /r dir  /s /B  > sources.txt` then `sources.txt` will contain the full path to itself as the first argument. That would **not** be a correct `javac` argument. I suggest you limit the listing to explicitly just `*.java` files: `cmd /r dir "*.java" /s /B`.

Answer (score 1):

That error message implies that PowerShell tries to interpret `@sources.txt` which you don't want. You want to pass that string verbatim to `javac`. To do so, you need to quote the argument:

```
javac "@sources.txt"
```

Comment: I already tried that, here it is the error after I run it as string:  javac : javac: invalid flag: :

At line:1 char:5

+     javac "@sources.txt"

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (javac: invalid flag: ::String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: What Java version are you using? What's the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: javac : javac 1.8.0_73

At line:1 char:1

+ javac -version

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (javac 1.8.0_73:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: It works for me and I'm don't know PS enough to make sense of it. Please post a [minial, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your PS script with that demonstrates the error. The `@file` support exists since at least Java 6, so that should not the issue.

Comment: Later edit: Modified the original question

Comment: @learner123: don't use the comments for this kind of info, edit it into your question.