# How do i create an argfile for use with javac in Powershell?

Tags: java, powershell, javac

I have read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html#command-line-argument-files) including the section that exemplifies Command Line Argument Files but can't figure out how to get it working in PowerShell.  Here's what I have done:

First, I can compile a Driver.java file using (in windows PowerShell, javac version 17.0.3):

```
>>javac Driver.java
```

But, I would like to figure out how to use argument files (`@filename`).

I have tried to create a file called `files.txt` with 1 entry in it listed as `Driver.java` and then use javac with @file to specify what to compile:

```
PS-pluto>>dir -n *.java >files
PS-pluto>javac @files
```

I tried creating `files`, and `files.txt`.  Driver.java is definitely the entry, but the javac command doesn't work.  I am running this from the folder where files and Driver are located.

I read the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67121848/javac-splatting-operator-cannot-be-used-in-powershell-and-cmd) which indicated that I needed to add quotes, and tried this (again, with and without .txt):

```
PS-pluto>>dir -n *.java >files
PS-pluto>>javac "@files"
```

This may work, but doesn't solve the problem.  Now I get a new error:

```
error: invalid flag:  ■Driver.java
```

I have looked for hidden formatting in my txt file and only see the line return at the end of Driver.java.  Not sure what is wrong?

I know in this simplistic case using an argument file is overkill, but I am simply trying to figure out how it works...and cannot.

NOTE:  I already know how to compile this in an IDE or with a build tool.  I am trying to figure out how to do this in PowerShell, and admittedly, I am a novice PowerShell user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An *unquoted* `@` at the start of an argument is a PowerShell metacharacter and therefore needs to either be escaped as `` `@ `` or enclosed in a string literal.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, `>` creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files by default, which `javac` most likely cannot handle.

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, BOM-less UTF8 is now the (consistent) default, so `>` would work as is.
  - In *Windows PowerShell*, the simplest solution is to pipe to `Set-Content -Encoding Ascii`, assuming that the file names contain ASCII-range characters only.

```bash
# Create file "files" as an ASCII file.
# Note: The Get-ChildItem call is `dir -n *.java` fully spelled out.
Get-ChildItem -Name *.java | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii files

# Escape @ as `@ to treat it literally.
javac `@files
```

If the file names contain non-ASCII characters and `javac` requires BOM-less UTF-8 encoding, more work is needed, because in Windows PowerShell you cannot directly create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).

Comment: thanks #mklement0 - knowing the format and using the back-tick fixed the problem.  Note - no non-ascii characters were included, but I think I will move to PowerShell(Core) anyways